# Throwing a ListAdapter (from a companion object) as a Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-listadapter

I've a listAdapter defined this way:

```
companion object {
public val otrosSubmitListAdapter = OtrosSubmitListAdapter()
}
```

I'd like the  OtrosSubmitListAdapter() to be thrown as a different thread than the fragment I call it from.

Something like

```
public val otrosSubmitListAdapter = Thread()
```

Whose behaviour would be to call OtrosSubmitListAdapter() in a different Thread.

Would this be possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, it is weird to initialize just the Adapter in another thread, because Adapter should be lightweight, if it has to do something, it has to delegate to correct classes **when needed**.

Answer, if `OtrosSubmitListAdapter` constructor or init code does not touch UI Views, it can be called from other "threads". Not sure but i believe creating Thread does not have a return type, it is for hosting works and terminate. So one way would be using coroutines:

```
someCoroutineScope.launch{
   val otrosSubmitListAdapter = withContext(someDispatcher){OtrosSubmitListAdapter()}
   ...
}
```